# Bash script: "read" command not responding

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing a bash script that will

1. Downlaod a website's html code into a file "index.html"
2. Ask user for file type and search "index.html" for number of matched file types

This is the function that will complete step 2:

```
1. function findFiles() {
2.      echo "Enter file type to search for (include '.') || Type EXIT to terminate program "
3.      read fileType
4.
5.      while [[ "$fileType" != "EXIT" ]];
6.      do
7.          if [[ $(grep -q $fileType index.html) = 1 ]]; then
8.              grep -F "$fileType" index.html >> foundFiles.txt
9.          fi
10.     done
11.
12.     rm index.html
13. };
```

When executed, line 3 prompts for user input but does not respond when I hit enter, example follows:

```
2021-09-26 12:41:06 (2.66 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [94126]

Enter file type to search for (include '.') || Type EXIT to terminate program 
.pdf
.txt



foo
AAAA
```

I have tried declaring a local variable `$fileType` first, using `read -p` and putting a semicolon at the end of line 3. The result is always the same and I have not been able to find a solution. I'm aware that what follows line 3 is flawed, but I just would only like help with line 3 as the following lines are something I would like to work on myself to learn more about bash scripting.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Show us how you're executing this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't supposed to respond. It is doing exactly what it should: it reads the input and assigns it to the variable `fileType`. However, you then have a `while` loop which is checking the value of a variable that never changes:

```
while [[ "$fileType" != "EXIT" ]];
```

Since the value of `$fileType` is set only once and before the `while` loop, that `while` becomes an infinite loop unless you pass `EXIT` on the first try. In any case, your script wouldn't work anyway since the output of `grep -q pattern file` will never be `1`. In fact, it will always be empty since that's what `grep -q` does. I suspect you meant to check the exit status of the command but, even that is pointless: there is no benefit in reading the entire file once with `grep -q` only to then read it all over again with `grep -F`.

Here's a working version of your function:

```sh
function findFiles() {
  while [[ "$fileType" != "EXIT" ]];
  do
    echo "Enter file type to search for (include '.') || Type EXIT to terminate program "
    read fileType
    grep -F "$fileType" index.html >> foundFiles.txt
  done
     rm index.html
 };
```

Or, if you want to avoid creating an empty `foundFiles.txt` if no matches were found, you can try:

```
function findFiles() {
  while [[ "$fileType" != "EXIT" ]];
  do
    echo "Enter file type to search for (include '.') || Type EXIT to terminate program "
    read fileType
    if grep -qm1 "$fileType" index.html; then
      grep -F "$fileType" index.html >> foundFiles.txt
    fi
  done
     rm index.html
 };
```

The `-m` ensures the `grep` exits after the first match so you don't need to read the whole file twice. Note how I am not using the command substitution (`$(command)`) syntax since I am checking that the command was successful, and not trying to use its output.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this has fixed my problem and I understand your solution, which helps me a lot. I'll work on the script to make sure it does exactly what I'm trying to get it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be catching yourself in an endless loop. If the user did not type "EXIT", then the `while` loop will go on forever. Any additional text you type is just being echoed to the terminal.